# TextBox GotFocus event not responding

Tags: c#, winforms

Very simple:

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.textBox1.Text = "AAA";
}
```

This does not appear to be doing anything. my textBox is called textBox1. No error, but it is not doing what I want.

Any idea?

Comment: This question is incredibly unclear. Are you asking why this method is never invoked, or what?

Comment: What's notable is what is missing from the question: "And I made sure that the event handler is registered".  So it probably isn't, especially since the GotFocus event is hidden.  Click the lightning bold icon in the Properties window and double-click Enter.

Comment: have you made sure the proper event on your text box is hooked up to your textBox_GotFocus method in the designer? what is it that you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form's constructor, make sure you have this:

```
this.textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_GotFocus);
```

The GotFocus event is hidden from the designer, so you have to do it yourself.

As Hans pointed out, GotFocus is basically replaced by the Enter event, and you should use that instead:

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.textBox1.Text = "AAA";
}
```